# Setting global variables with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I'm relatively new into this and tried a little bit of code, but encountered a problem.

In my App I have a global variable which keeps track wether a user chose his username already or not. 
Once he has picked his name I want to set this variable permanently to true so I can disable the segue which leads to the Username ViewController.

But I can't preset the variable since the code would re-initialize the variable everytime I re-open the app.
And I still got my problems setting it up with UserDefaults.

I hope I was able to explain my problem more or less.

Comment: It is hard to help without any code, can you please show the code you used and where to get/set the UserDefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserDefaults getters will return nil if it is not set, so you don't need to set a bool, just check if the value has been set like so:

```
if let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"username") {
    // user has created username, and username has the unwrapped value in it
} else {
    // go to set username screen
}
```

Make sure that after they go to the set username screen you set the username key in the UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(value, forKey:"username")
```

Where `value` is the value they entered.

If you want to reset a value in the UserDefaults (i.e. they log out) use the removeObject function:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:"username")
```

That will make it so `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"username")` will return `nil` again.

Adding a bool for checking will just make one more cog that can screw it all up if you forget to set it...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this, exactly what I searched for :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a bool value to userDefault

```
UserDefaults.standard.setBool(true, forKey: "is_userName")
```

And retrieve the value for checking

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "is_userName") {
      // User have created username 
} else {
      // Go to set username screen
}
```

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks!